# Save with different name in C# Form Application

Tags: c#, forms, dialog

I have problem when I try to save my spx file with different name.

I tried lots of ways but it did not work.

How can I save my voice recorder with different name ?

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Export")
            {

                using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
                {
                    DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

                    if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
                    {
                        string files = fbd.SelectedPath;
                        string source = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

                        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(source);
                        string DirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(source);

                        try
                        {
                            File.Copy(Path.Combine(DirectoryName, FileName), Path.Combine(files, FileName));

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You have same voice recorder in that file.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code above?

Comment: No problem with code. I don't know what can I write.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to specify a new filename in the File.Copy command.

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(DirectoryName, FileName), Path.Combine(files, "NewFileName"));
```

[image]

Comment: User must enter the name from application. How can I get ?

Comment: You could use an input field where the user can input the new name of the file :)

Comment: Yes I know I should use SaveFileDialog. But how can I use that in here ? @Kiksen

Comment: I sadly do not know anything about SaveFileDialog :) I am a web developer. Try goodle it or check this out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6uBAfFICVE

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the name on the end, if you need the user to input this name, you just have to put an new variable on the  method

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(DirectoryName, FileName), Path.Combine(files, newFileName));
```

Here if you want to use SaveFileDialog.

```
 SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveDialog.ShowDialog();
            CopyFile("C://", "New Text Document.txt", files, saveDialog.FileName);
```